# How to get CMS / Catalogue page text and content to behave responsive?

Tags: magento2, css, rwd, luma-theme

Added text to CMS pages or Catalogue pages in Magento 2 are not behaving responsive. All other parts of the page are responsive. How to get the CMS / catalogue text to behave responsive as well?

On large screen the text is fine but when displayed on a mobile device the text (block) is not adapted and the content is running of the screen!
I'm using a Template based on the Luma Template.

Comment: put the content div width=100% in style. Then it will adapt.

Comment: share screenshot.

Comment: I tried adding 

#div{
 width: 100%;
} 
or
.div{
 width: 100%;
} 
But that did not work. I also have a widget on the CMS page showing 4 new products horizontal row and these are also not responsive? I had a look at other pages but can not figure out what css is applied.

Comment: is it possible to share your page url

Comment: By deleting the css I already added it worked again. So this issue is solved.